# Cannot get LAMP stack working on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04.2 installed as a virtual machine (VirtualBox) in my MacBook Pro. I am trying to get my LAMP (Linux,Apache, MySQL and PHP) stack to run a web server, but I just cant get not even the Apache welcome page (by typing my IP address in my browser).

I suspect that this is due to a network misconfiguration. I tried to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` config to:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.100
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    bridge_ports eth0 vbox0 vbox1

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

As the Ubuntu documentation suggests, but I had no success in getting my Apache server to work. Whenever I installed Ubuntu, I pre-installed the OpenSSH, LAMP and MailServer bundles, so I do not know if this somehow interferes with the configuration a little bit.

Also, my MacBook Pro is a recent model so I only have Wi-Fi. I am configuring the Network of the Virtual Machine in VirtualBox under “Settings > Network” and I am choosing Attached To: “Bridged Adapter” and selecting my Wi-Fi adapter (AirPort) like so -> Name: en0: Wi-Fi (airport)

Does anybody have a clue why I cannot type my static IP and get the Apache welcome page?

Comment: You can't bridge to Wi-Fi. You'll have to use a routed or NAT network instead.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for clarifying. Do you mind to elaborate on that topic?

Comment: @JakeGould I am trying to access it from another computer through the internet. Say, as a remote server. How should I configure my network settings then? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

as per comments - your problem spans from the fact that you've configured wrong interface for your VM. While unfamiliar with the VirtualBox inner workings I will suggest general workflow (that is widely used nowadays with containers and such):

- create VM with a "normal" non-routable IP as per usual. For example RedHat family assigns default network of 192.168.122/24 as a default network for VMs
- use your host's firewall (be it Mac's ipw or whatever they use today or Linux iptables if you installed Linux for your host) and "nat" any inbound traffic on *:80 over to the IP of your VM.

  - as an option to this you may install some simple reverse proxy like nginx pound etc. and make it listen on